# Font rendering problems in Google Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, font-face

I'm designing a webpage using HTML5/CSS. I'm using the custom font "Reboard" for my navigation bar, and I've added it in my stylesheet using the following code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Reboard';
    src: local('fonts/Reboard.ttf');
}
```

The font looks fine on Firefox and Safari. However, on Chrome the font renders with some weird spacing between the letters. I have attached the following images to demonstrate the difference:

Good Rendering on Mozilla and Safari
[image: Good rendering]

Bad Rendering on Google Chrome
[image: Bad rendering]

There is one interesting thing I've also noticed. When I zoom in a bit on Google Chrome, the font will magically be fixed with normal spacing. Not sure what to do to fix the problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you used  .woff font type also please define MIME type as well in config file.

Comment: let me make it as answer, so would be beneficial for other users.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem. I had to use the WOFF font type and declare the format as 'woff'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem appear when the webpage goes Live and font is missing at that time. 
To fix this issue have to define the `.woff` font MIME type in config file.

> Note: `.woff` font type is accepted by all latest browser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a known issue in Chrome.

Credits: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692#c68

it appears rearranging the @font-face CSS rule to allow svg's to appear 'first' fixes this problem.

```
example:

-before--------------

@font-face {
font-family: 'chunk-webfont';
src: url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot');
src: url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}


-after--------------

@font-face {
font-family: 'chunk-webfont';
src: url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot');
src: url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.svg') format('svg'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../../includes/fonts/chunk-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

A lot of people on here have posted topics regarding issues related to this.

Check this link for more info:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692